# R : How to increase height of grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

Is there a way to increase the space for plotting when making a unbalanced grid of plots. See the below, where max area is unutilised.

```
library(gridExtra) 
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=mpg))
grid.arrange(p, arrangeGrob(p,p,
                       p,p, 
                       heights = c(1/1.5,1/1.5),nrow=2),
         nrow=3,heights=c(1,1.2,1.2))
```

[image]

Comment: You mean - how to fill space bellow with 4 bottom plots?

Comment: The problem comes from the `nrow=3` at the end of the `grid.arrange()`. The arrangeGrob produce a single graphical object, so you only want two rows of graphic (and 2 heights values) in your `grid.arrange()`.

Comment: @PoGibas no. Use the space for the existing ones only. enlarged plots

Comment: @xraynaud you solved it !!! Kudos !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = mpg))

p / {
   p + {p} + plot_layout(ncol = 2)
 } / {
   p + {p} + plot_layout(ncol = 2)
 } + 
 plot_layout(nrow = 3, widths = c(1, 1.2, 1.2))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.arrange(p,p,p,p,p, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,1:5), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```